# JavaFX undecorated window, Windows 10 edge maximize event

Tags: java, windows, javafx

When dragging a window to the edge of the screen in, for example, windows 10, the window will maximize. Example:
https://gyazo.com/365bd3d315fa4261c602711fde46c92b

But when I do it with my undecorated javaFX application it doesn't work:
https://gyazo.com/ef94800081db5337b4bb7238d092a424

How would I do this in JavaFX?

Here's the code I use to move my window:

```
double xOffset = 0;
double yOffset = 0;

layout.setOnMousePressed(event ->
{
    xOffset = event.getSceneX();
    yOffset = event.getSceneY();
});
layout.setOnMouseDragged(event ->
{
    window.setX(event.getScreenX() - xOffset);
    window.setY(event.getScreenY() - yOffset);
});
```

Comment: Can't you just check the event.getScreenY() value, if it is 0 and then maximize your window yourself?

Comment: @GAlexMES while that would work for that specific case, there are other things like when you move the window to the side of the screen it coves up half of the screen and asks the user to select another window to cover the other half.

Comment: @WhiteAutumn you can't do that, atleast not in a cross platform way. When you make the window undecorated, and make the title bar on your own, you override the native bar which is given by windows.

Comment: @Shashwat I know that I can't do it cross platform, that's why I wrote "Windows" in the title. I guess that could and probably in most cases will be interpreted as "undercoated windows" Let me make the title a little more clearer

Comment: I am not sure, if that is possible. That resizing thing is somehow Windows native, but the Java VM is not using it. I think, you cannot forece your program to use it, because the VM can't do that. But I am not sure, please correct me!

Comment: @GAlexMES You are correct. I guess the O.P could use a **windows native library**, but I am not aware of any libraries which could do what he requires

Comment: @WhiteAutumn don't know if it helps, but you could try https://github.com/java-native-access/jna

Comment: @Shashwat thanks. Do you know, if there are any planing to add that feature to Java 9 or 10?

Comment: @GAlexMES well, not any that I'm aware of. Anyways, this isn't a issue with **java**, because to fix something on 1 `OS`, you can't break the code on other operating systems.

Comment: @Shashwat You say that this isn't an issue with java? But look at for example Discord. While Discord isn't written in java, it does use an undercoated window and keep the Windows specific drag events